# I am getting a RuntimeError

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am getting a runtime error" RuntimeError: Expected 3D (unbatched) or 4D (batched) input to conv2d, but got input of size: [16, 18432]". Please help.Below is the disply model:

MyEnsemble(
(modelA): AlexNet(
(features): Sequential(
(0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(11, 11), stride=(4, 4), padding=(2, 2))
(1): ReLU(inplace=True)
(2): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
(3): Conv2d(64, 192, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1), padding=(2, 2))
(4): ReLU(inplace=True)
(5): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
(6): Conv2d(192, 384, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
(7): ReLU(inplace=True)
(8): Conv2d(384, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
(9): ReLU(inplace=True)
(10): Identity()
)
(avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(6, 6))
(classifier): Sequential()
)
(modelB): AlexNet(
(features): Sequential(
(0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(11, 11), stride=(4, 4), padding=(2, 2))
(1): ReLU(inplace=True)
(2): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
(3): Conv2d(64, 192, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1), padding=(2, 2))
(4): ReLU(inplace=True)
(5): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
(6): Conv2d(192, 384, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
(7): ReLU(inplace=True)
(8): Conv2d(384, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
(9): ReLU(inplace=True)
(10): Identity()
)
(avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(6, 6))
(classifier): Sequential()
)
(features): Conv2d(512, 2, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
(classifier): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=2, bias=True)
)

I also want to remove these line from my model:
(avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(6, 6))
(classifier): Sequential()
Thanks in advance.

I am concatenate two pretrained alexnet models and after that add a convolution and full connected layer at the end.

Comment: provide the code you are using, so that we can help you

Comment: for code please check this link: https://nekobin.com/fucisepiku. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not share links, just modify your question to include the minimum code required.

Comment: ValueError: Layer "model" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 224, 224, 3) dtype=float32>]. giving error in the fit: history1=add_model.fit(
  train_ds, #np.stack
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=5)

Comment: and when i change it to: model_history = add_model.fit(x=(X_train, y_train), epochs=5, validation_data=(X_test, y_test)). Error is: ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'model' (type Functional).   
    Input 0 of layer "block1_conv1_vgg19" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (32,)

Comment: The main problem is in your train_ds, it doesn't have the required shape, ie `B, C, H, W`.  In the error,  it says that you are feeding the model data of shape [16, 18432].  You need to resize your train_ds correctly, such that it has 4 dims instead of 2, ie: B, C, H, W.

Comment: Thanks. But how Can i change it to the right one.